# how to set app icon of app in xamarin.forms app for IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, appicon

i have idea about how to set app icon image where we were putting all respective size icon images in resource folder.

in recent xamarin update there is no need to add multiple size images for splash screen  using storyboard.

so  my question is there something also for app icon also? so we need not to add multiple icon images??

any suggestion most welcome.

Comment: Have you checked the official guide before posting this question? iOS specific guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/app-icons/ xamarin.forms guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Icons

Comment: yes.i checked this

Comment: Not possible, we still need to add  multiple size icons in Asset Catalogs.

Comment: @ColeXia yes cole..u are right..

Answer (score 0):

Add in Asset Catalog.Add an different sizes of icon and set that in infoplist.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Assets.xcassets in Xamarin ios project, you will get a default AppIcon image set there which is by default using Xamarin logo.
Replace those images with you icons, make sure the resolutions your image follows the required resolutions/pixels for each (1x,2x&3x) type of images.

Comment: The question asks if it is possible to not have to add the multiple sizes. As the OP states in his original question he knows how to add the icons, but is looking for a way to only add one.